# DynamicJasper - How to add a subreport as columns?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

**Overview**

- I have a Java class which has an `ArrayList` that must be printed to
  the jasperReport as a subreport.
- I'm using DynamicJasper library.
- The example on this question has been modified so it can be reproduced. However the data is different on the real case.

**Problem**

The current code Ive come with, prints the subreport in another line. Its ugly. I wanted the subreport to just be a group of columns that are concatenated.

To make it clear, here's the current result[image: Current issue]

And What I want is something like this: [image]

**Current code**

```
public class Test_subReport {

    protected static JasperPrint jp;
    protected static JasperReport jr;
    protected static Map params = new HashMap();
    protected static DynamicReport dr;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException, ColumnBuilderException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Test_subReport t = new Test_subReport();
        t.createReport();

    }

    public void createReport() throws SQLException, ColumnBuilderException, ClassNotFoundException {

        ArrayList<Fruit> createMockDataset = createMockDataset();

        Style titleStyle = new Style();
        titleStyle.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.CENTER);
        titleStyle.setFont(Font.ARIAL_SMALL_BOLD);

        Style dataStyle = new Style();
        dataStyle.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.CENTER);
        dataStyle.setFont(Font.ARIAL_SMALL);
        dataStyle.setBlankWhenNull(true);

        final List items = SortUtils.sortCollection(createMockDataset, Arrays.asList(new String[]{"name", "description"}));

        FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();
        drb.setTemplateFile("templatePortrait.jrxml", true, true, true, true);
        drb.addColumn("name", "name", String.class.getName(), 30, dataStyle)
                .addColumn("description", "description", String.class.getName(), 50, dataStyle)
                .setTitle("Report")
                .setSubtitle("")
                .setPrintBackgroundOnOddRows(true)
                .setUseFullPageWidth(true);

        drb.addGroups(2);
        try {
            drb.addField("evaluations", List.class.getName());
            drb.addSubreportInGroupHeader(1, createSubreport("Evaluations"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test_subReport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        DynamicReport dynamicReport = drb.build();

        dynamicReport.setTitleStyle(titleStyle);

        HashMap parametros = new HashMap();
        parametros.put("dataRelatorio", MyTools.getDataPorExtenso());

        doReport(dynamicReport, items, parametros);
    }

    public void doReport(final DynamicReport _report, final Collection _data, HashMap parametros) {
        try {
            JRDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(_data);

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(_report, new ClassicLayoutManager(), beanCollectionDataSource, parametros);

            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private DynamicReport createHeaderSubreport(String title) throws Exception {
        FastReportBuilder rb = new FastReportBuilder();
        DynamicReport dr = rb
                .addColumn("id", "id", Integer.class.getName(), 100)
                .addColumn("score", "score", Double.class.getName(), 50)
                .setMargins(5, 5, 20, 20)
                .setUseFullPageWidth(true)
                .setWhenNoDataNoPages()
                .setTitle(title)
                .build();
        return dr;
    }

    private Subreport createSubreport(String title) throws Exception {
        SubReportBuilder srb = new SubReportBuilder();
        srb.setDynamicReport(createHeaderSubreport(title), new ClassicLayoutManager())
                .setStartInNewPage(true)
                .setDataSource(DJConstants.DATA_SOURCE_ORIGIN_FIELD, DJConstants.DATA_SOURCE_TYPE_COLLECTION, "evaluations");
        return srb.build();
    }

    public ArrayList<Fruit> createMockDataset() {
        ArrayList<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<>();

        Fruit f1 = new Fruit();
        f1.name = "Apple X1";
        f1.description = "Yummy yummy apple for the stackoverflow readers 1";

        Fruit f2 = new Fruit();
        f2.name = "Apple Ag";
        f2.description = "Yummy yummy apple for the stackoverflow readers 2";

        Fruit f3 = new Fruit();
        f3.name = "Apple Mn";
        f3.description = "Yummy yummy apple for the stackoverflow readers 3";

        Fruit f4 = new Fruit();
        f4.name = "Apple O2";
        f4.description = "Yummy yummy apple for the stackoverflow readers 4";

        //Evaluations for f1
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Evaluation e = new Evaluation();
            e.id = i;
            e.score = Math.random() * 10;
            f1.evaluations.add(e);
        }

        //evaluations for f4
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Evaluation e = new Evaluation();
            e.id = i;
            e.score = Math.random() * 10;
            f4.evaluations.add(e);
        }

        fruits.add(f1);
        fruits.add(f2);
        fruits.add(f3);
        fruits.add(f4);

        return fruits;

    }

    public class Fruit {

        public String name;
        public String description;
        public ArrayList<Evaluation> evaluations = new ArrayList<Evaluation>();

        public Fruit() {

        }

        public Fruit(String name, String description) {
            this.name = name;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public ArrayList<Evaluation> getEvaluations() {
            return evaluations;
        }

        public void setEvaluations(ArrayList<Evaluation> evaluations) {
            this.evaluations = evaluations;
        }

    }

    public class Evaluation {

        public int id;
        public double score;

        public Evaluation() {

        }

        public Evaluation(int id, double score) {
            this.id = id;
            this.score = score;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public double getScore() {
            return score;
        }

        public void setScore(double score) {
            this.score = score;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably there isn't way to implement desired behavior using subreports.

I guess, that the best way to do it is to use just groups, but data model should be a bit modified for that.

Here is my solution:

```
public class Test_subReport {

    protected static JasperPrint jp;
    protected static JasperReport jr;
    protected static Map params = new HashMap();
    protected static DynamicReport dr;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException, ColumnBuilderException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Test_subReport t = new Test_subReport();
        t.createReport();

    }

    public void createReport() throws SQLException, ColumnBuilderException, ClassNotFoundException {

        List<DataWrapper> createMockDataset = wrapData(createMockDataset());

        Style titleStyle = new Style();
        titleStyle.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.CENTER);
        titleStyle.setFont(Font.ARIAL_SMALL_BOLD);

        Style dataStyle = new Style();
        dataStyle.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.CENTER);
        dataStyle.setFont(Font.ARIAL_SMALL);
        dataStyle.setBlankWhenNull(true);

        final List items = SortUtils.sortCollection(createMockDataset, Arrays.asList(new String[]{"name", "description"}));

        FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();
        drb.setTemplateFile("templatePortrait.jrxml", true, true, true, true);
        drb.addColumn("name", "name", String.class.getName(), 30, dataStyle)
                .addColumn("description", "description", String.class.getName(), 100, dataStyle)
                .addColumn("id", "id", Integer.class.getName(), 30, dataStyle)
                .addColumn("score", "score", Double.class.getName(), 30, false, "$ #.00", dataStyle)
                .setTitle("Report")
                .setWhenNoDataNoPages()
                .setAllowDetailSplit(false)
                .setUseFullPageWidth(true);

        drb.addGroups(2);

        DynamicReport dynamicReport = drb.build();
        dynamicReport.setTitleStyle(titleStyle);

        HashMap parametros = new HashMap();
        parametros.put("dataRelatorio", MyTools.getDataPorExtenso());

        doReport(dynamicReport, items, parametros);
    }

    public void doReport(final DynamicReport _report, final Collection _data, HashMap parametros) {
        try {
            JRDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(_data);

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(_report, new ClassicLayoutManager(), beanCollectionDataSource, parametros);

            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<DataWrapper> wrapData(List<Fruit> fruits) {
        List<DataWrapper> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Fruit fruit : fruits) {

            if (fruit.getEvaluations().isEmpty()) {
                dataList.add(new DataWrapper(fruit.name, fruit.description, null, null));
            } else {
                for (Evaluation evaluation : fruit.getEvaluations()) {
                    dataList.add(new DataWrapper(fruit.name, fruit.description, evaluation.id, evaluation.score));
                }
            }
        }

        return dataList;
    }

    public List<Fruit> createMockDataset() {
        ArrayList<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<>();

        Fruit f1 = new Fruit();
        f1.name = "Apple X1";
        f1.description = "Yummy yummy apple for the stackoverflow readers 1";

        Fruit f2 = new Fruit();
        f2.name = "Apple Ag";
        f2.description = "Yummy yummy apple for the stackoverflow readers 2";

        Fruit f3 = new Fruit();
        f3.name = "Apple Mn";
        f3.description = "Yummy yummy apple for the stackoverflow readers 3";

        Fruit f4 = new Fruit();
        f4.name = "Apple O2";
        f4.description = "Yummy yummy apple for the stackoverflow readers 4";

        //Evaluations for f1
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Evaluation e = new Evaluation();
            e.id = i;
            e.score = Math.random() * 10;
            f1.evaluations.add(e);
        }

        //evaluations for f4
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Evaluation e = new Evaluation();
            e.id = i;
            e.score = Math.random() * 10;
            f4.evaluations.add(e);
        }

        fruits.add(f1);
        fruits.add(f2);
        fruits.add(f3);
        fruits.add(f4);

        return fruits;
    }

    public class Fruit {

        public String name;
        public String description;
        public ArrayList<Evaluation> evaluations = new ArrayList<Evaluation>();

        public Fruit() {

        }

        public Fruit(String name, String description) {
            this.name = name;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public ArrayList<Evaluation> getEvaluations() {
            return evaluations;
        }

        public void setEvaluations(ArrayList<Evaluation> evaluations) {
            this.evaluations = evaluations;
        }

    }

    public class Evaluation {

        public int id;
        public double score;

        public Evaluation() {

        }

        public Evaluation(int id, double score) {
            this.id = id;
            this.score = score;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public double getScore() {
            return score;
        }

        public void setScore(double score) {
            this.score = score;
        }

    }

    public class DataWrapper {

        public String name;
        public String description;

        public Integer id;
        public Double score;

        public DataWrapper() {

        }

        public DataWrapper(String name, String description, Integer id, Double score) {
            this.name = name;
            this.description = description;
            this.id = id;
            this.score = score;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Double getScore() {
            return score;
        }

        public void setScore(Double score) {
            this.score = score;
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the result:
[image: Result of code execution]

Feel free to ask if you have some question.

Comment: I thought about this solution but.. I mean, Im gonna have to wrap every class. Its a work-around. It works, and Im glad you replied but im not sure its actually the best resolution. I mean, the devs should do something about it?

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean:). I'm also not fully satisfied with this solution.